# How to configure Stored Procedures Inbound Channel Adapter using java config (instead of xml)

Tags: spring-integration

How do I configure `@InboundChannelAdapter` for Stored Procedure (Oracle) in Spring integration through Java Config? I find the examples/reference using xml configuration but cannot find reference on Java config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#configuring-with-java-configuration-13).

> The following Spring Boot application shows an example of how to configure the inbound adapter with Java:

```
SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = StudentDomain.class)
public class JpaJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(JpaJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public JpaExecutor jpaExecutor() {
        JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManagerFactory);
        jpaExecutor.setJpaQuery("from Student");
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "jpaInputChannel",
                     poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "${poller.interval}"))
    public MessageSource<?> jpaInbound() {
        return new JpaPollingChannelAdapter(jpaExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "jpaInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return message -> System.out.println(message.getPayload());
    }

}
```

and [with the Java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#configuring-with-the-java-dsl-14)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = StudentDomain.class)
public class JpaJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(JpaJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingAdapterFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jpa.inboundAdapter(this.entityManagerFactory)
                        .entityClass(StudentDomain.class)
                        .maxResults(1)
                        .expectSingleResult(true),
                e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(new OnlyOnceTrigger())))
            .channel(c -> c.queue("pollingResults"))
            .get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry - that's JPA, not stored procs - but it's the same concept. You can find the class names in the XML schema. The `MessageSource<?>` is a `StoredProcPollingChannelAdapter` and you need a `StoredProcExecutor` which gets a `DataSource`. There isn't currently a `Jdbc` DSL factory, but you can still use the DSL with `.from(source)`.

Comment: There is a [test case with Java configuration here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/StoredProcJavaConfigTests.java#L97).

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell for the reference. really helpful.